# Pantalla negra al ejecutar pygame principiante

Tags: python, pygame

No sé porque la pantalla aparece negra al ejecutar pygame, tengo q hacer un juego para el martes y ni siquiera logro ejecutar la pantalla

```python
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# Constantes

ancho = 900
alto = 500
#===========================================================
#===========================================================

def imagen(filename, transparent=False):
        try: image = pygame.image.load(filename)
        except pygame.error :
                raise SystemExit()
        image = image.convert()
        if transparent:
                color = image.get_at((0,0))
                image.set_colorkey(color, RLEACCEL)
        return image

#===========================================================

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ancho, alto))
    pygame.display.set_caption("messi")
    
    fondo=imagen("imagenes/fondo.png")
    messi=imagen("imagenes/messi.aseprite", True)
    
    fondo=pygame.transform.scale(fondo, (800, 200))
    
    screen.blit (fondo, (0,0))
    screen.blit (messi, (45, 55))
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: `pygame` es una librería que abstrae una API gráfica. Tienee un único lienzo y debes limpiarlo, dibujar y finalmente mostrarlo en pantalla. Viendo [los ejemplos](https://www.pygame.org/docs/) entiendo que no haces ninguna de las 2 cosas. Seguramente tengas que poner esas 3 líneas dentro del `while`. (las de `blit` y ` flip`)

Comment: Pygame no soporta .ase/.aseprite directamente.